# How to execute a for loop in bash as a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to execute a loop as a string. This:

```
bash -c "for l in $(/bin/ls /dir1); do /bin/ln -sf $l /dir2/; done"
```

Gives an error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `file1'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `file1'
```

file1 is one of those that I want to turn into symlinks in the first directory.

Comment: Using single quote instead `bash -c 'for l in /dir1/*; do /bin/ln -sf "$l" /dir2/; done'`

Comment: Don't parse ls output: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @cuonglm: your command doesn't do exactly the same thing he's trying to do.  He's creating relative symlinks to files that don't necessarily exist, based on names found in a different directory.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Not sure what you mean, what is the difference between `ls /dir` with using glob?

Comment: `ls /dir` lists just the filenames, not the full paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse ls output: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Also, in this example you don't need a loop, just let `ln` loop over args.  `cd` to the directory you're creating the symlinks in, if you want relative symlink targets to work when you use relative paths from the current directory to generate them.

```sh
(cd /dir1 && ln -sf -- * /dir2)      # make broken symlinks in dir2
(cd /dir2 && ln -sf -- ../dir1/* .)  # make relative symlinks
ln -sf /dir1/* /dir2/                # make absolute symlinks
```

`(subshell)` to avoid changing directory in the current shell.

You can also use `ln -sf -t /dir2 -- *`, which is useful with `find -exec ln -t /dir {} +`, because `find -exec {} +` can only put the list at the end of the command line.

GNU `cp` also has `-l` and `-s` options, to make hard / symbolic links.

Comment: It should be noted that it won't create links to the files in /dir1 inside /dir2, for which it should be `ln -s /dir1/* /dir2/` (hard to tell what the OP wants)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Yeah, probably a good idea to include all 3 things the OP might want.  Thanks for the `--` edit.  I always remember to quote my variables, but I often forget about `--` to protect things other than the shell from weird stuff in filenames.  >.<.

Comment: Note that `(cd /dir2 && ln -sf -- ../dir1/* .)` may not work  if `/dir2` itself is a symlink.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: yeah, that can get confusing.  `cd -P` before using `../` relative paths is often a good idea.  `-P` = physical, as opposed to the usual logical mode.